# Callbacks within a switch

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to work out how to wait until all functions specified are completed before calling a different function. Right now I have something along the lines of this:

```
for (i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++){
    SwitchCall(valueArray[i]);
}

function SwitchCall(value){
    switch(value){
        case 1: FunctionOne(); break;
        case 2: FunctionTwo(); break;
        case 3: FunctionThree(); break;
    }
}

SomeOtherFunction()
```

Where `valueArray` is an array containing some subset of {1,2,3}. I need all of the functions specified in the array to be completed before calling `SomeOtherFunction`. I'd imagine I need to put some sort of callback into the three functions, but I can't call `SomeOtherFunction` in those callbacks because I might need the other functions to complete first. How do I wait for all these functions to finish before moving on?

Comment: You might want to read on promises in javascript:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Are any of the functions asynchronous?

Comment: @KevBot They're all asynchronous.

Comment: Here is a good example of promises with JQuery: [Making Promises With jQuery Deferred](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Promises with jQuery Deferred

```
var async1 = FunctionOne();
var async2 = FunctionTwo();
var async3 = FunctionThree();

$.when(async1, async2, async3).done(function(async1, async2, async3) {
  //When all done!
  SomeOtherFunction()
});
```

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/making-promises-with-jquery-deferred.html